# Kivy Recycleview doesn't update added data

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm once more stuck with my little Kivy Project.
The Idea is that the app lists folder names from a directory in a Recycleview list. I want to be able to add a Folder with the app in that directory, with the list being updated after the folder is created.

Showing the list and creating folders work. But I can't manage to get Recycleview to update. I tried every method I found online, but I think that the main problem is that I probably don't fully understand the relations between the different ids and how I can forward the updated list to RV. I know it has been covered many times here, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks a lot to everyone who takes the time to look over my problem.

My boiled down Python File:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from kivy.app import App
import pathlib
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty, BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

prjct_list = []
prjct_list_clean = []

entries = pathlib.Path.home() / 'Desktop' / 'Troubleshootdir'

def get_all_files(entries):
    prjct_list = []
    global prjct_list_clean
    file_iterator = entries.iterdir()
    for entry in sorted(file_iterator):
        if entry.is_dir():
            prjct_list.append(entry.name)
            prjct_list_clean = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith(''), prjct_list))
    return prjct_list_clean

class MessageBox(Popup):

    def popup_dismiss(self):
        self.dismiss()

class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior, RecycleBoxLayout):
    """ Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. """
    selected_value = StringProperty('')
    btn_info = ListProperty(prjct_list_clean)

class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button, Widget):
    """ Add selection support to the Label """
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        """ Catch and handle the view changes """
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)


#############################################   RV   #############################################
class RV(RecycleView):
    rv_layout = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        global prjct_list_clean
        get_all_files(entries)
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = []
        for subject in prjct_list_clean:
            self.data.append({'text':subject})
        rv = self.ids['rv_layout']
        rv.data = self.data

    def callback(self, text):
        self.ids.con_wksp.text += text

class Manager(Widget):
    new_wksp = ObjectProperty(None)

    def cre_wksp(self):
        path = Path(entries, 'Prfx_' + self.new_wksp.text, "Subfolder01/Subfolder02")
        os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
        path = Path(entries, 'Prfx_' + self.new_wksp.text, "01_" + self.new_wksp.text + ".APN", 'Subfolder02')
        os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)

class TroubleshootApp(BoxLayout, App,):
    def build(self):
        self.recycl = RV()
        self.add_widget(self.recycl)
        self.mnager = Manager()
        self.add_widget(self.mnager)
        return self

    def update_dir(self):
        get_all_files(entries)
        self.recycl.ids.rv_layout.data = prjct_list_clean

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TroubleshootApp().run()
```

My .kv file:

```
#:kivy 2.0.0

<SelectableButton>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    background_color: [153 / 255.0, 153 / 255.0, 153 / 255.0, 255 / 255.0]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: [230 / 255.0, 115 / 255.0, 0 / 255.0, 255 / 255.0]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<RV>:
    #rv_layout: rv_layout
    bar_width: 0
    viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        id: rv_layout
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 0.9, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: "vertical"

<Manager>:

    new_wksp: new_wksp

    FloatLayout:
        pos: 0, 0
        size: root.width, root.height

        Button:
            text: 'Create Folder'
            x: root.x * 1.1
            top: self.height and root.y + root.height * 0.5
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.15
            on_press:
                root.cre_wksp()

        TextInput:
            id: new_wksp
            x: root.x * 1
            top: self.height and root.y + root.height * 0.9
            size_hint: 1, 0.15
            padding: 0, (self.height-self.line_height)/2
            halign: 'center'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the new folder to your `RV` data. Just add a call to `update_dir()` at the end of your `cre_wksp()` method:

```
def cre_wksp(self):
    path = Path(entries, 'Prfx_' + self.new_wksp.text, "Subfolder01/Subfolder02")
    os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
    path = Path(entries, 'Prfx_' + self.new_wksp.text, "01_" + self.new_wksp.text + ".APN", 'Subfolder02')
    os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
    App.get_running_app().update_dir()
```

With some changes to the `update_dir()` method:

```
def update_dir(self):
    get_all_files(entries)
    data = []
    for subject in prjct_list_clean:
        data.append({'text':subject})
    self.recycl.data = data
```

Comment: John, thank you so much for your help once again. That did the trick, and made a lot of things much clearer for me just now. Your help is really appreciated!